Why does CommonDelegatingErrorHandler in spring-kafka not implement handleOne?
I'm trying to use the CommonDelegatingErrorHandler to delegate to a couple of different DefaultErrorHandler's depending on the exception thrown by the listener. My DefaultErrorHandler's have seekAfterError set to false as that's the behaviour I want (probably, my understanding of what it does isn't concrete)
My listener was initially consuming batches, which worked fine. I've just tried to convert it to an individual record consumer and found that exceptions aren't handled anymore because CommonDelegatingErrorHandler doesn't implement handleOne
Does anyone understand why this is the case? Looking at the CommonDelegatingErrorHandler code I can't see a reason for it to not implement handleOne, and it implements all of the other handleX methods from CommonErrorHandler
In my case, I can set seekAfterError to true in my DefaultErrorHandler's, which means the handleRemaining method is used, but ideally I wouldn't have to do that and could use either behaviour of the DefaultErrorHandler with the CommonDelegatingErrorHandler
Any insight would be much appreciated!

You would need to ask the authors of the class why they didn't implement it.

Looking at the class one reason might be performance, i.e. finding the delegate for just one record may incur too much overhead (and that's just a guess - only the authors know for sure). Another factor would be that isSeekAferError() is a method defined by FailedRecordProcessor which is not in the CommonErrorHandler hierarchy and thus CommonDelegatingErrorHandler doesn't know about that capability. - You should be able to roll your own subclass though and add support for handleOne().

Looks like an omission. The logic in the KafkaMessageListenerContainer is to call one or another method and apparently that handleOne() could be as a delegation as we have in the handleRemaining().

I've raised a PR to spring-kafka to have this added - https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-kafka/pull/3228
